# Downgrading Rails from 4 to 3.2 Console doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I coded this website for a client in Rails 4 but since it was my first deployed rails app, I thought every hosting provider with rails would support Ruby 2 and Rails 4 but much to my dismay I tried but Dreamhost and Site5 who both use Passenger which requires Rails 3 and ruby 1.8 so I have to downgrade the whole site.

I was going along ok until I tried to check something using rails c, but it didnt work. It just gave the usage as if I was executing it from outside my app folder.

Any ideas how I make this work?

**UPDATE**

I think the issue is that rails cannot figure out that my app is a rails app since it gives the same message as if it's not. How do I reformate my rails 4 app to look like a 3.2 app?

Comment: add rails gem in Gemfile , depends on your rails version

Comment: Seriously dude? If I've already coded the entire website and am in the process of downgrading, don't you think I would already have the rails gem in Gemfile? Read the question before commenting please.

Comment: what are you getting when you run `rails c`?

Comment: "It just gave the usage as if I was executing it from outside my app folder."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason rails console wasn't working is because when Rails 4 creates a new project there is no `script/rails` but there is when you create a Rails 3.2 project. I just created a dummy rails 3 application and copied `script/rails` into my root directory and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right (the 3) version of Rails and if it is declared correctly in your Gemfile

After that, try running

```
bundle exec rails c
```